# Number of solutions of the differential equation: $(1-t)y\frac{dy}{dt} = 1 - y^2, y(1/2) = 2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

\begin{array}{lcl} (1-t)y\frac{dy}{dt} = 1 - y^2 \\ y(1/2) = 2 \end{array}

Given this  differential equation, I was able to prove that there are multiple solutions that pass through the given point, by joining the solutions $y = \pm \sqrt{1 + 12(1-t)^2}$ and the solutions $ y = \pm 1 $, but not infinite, as it was stated in the exercise.
Is the plot with the red line a solution, too?

[image]

Could someone explain me what is wrong with my answer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you expect infinite?

Comment: @Phicar it was stated  in the exercise

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{lcl} (1-t)y\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 1 - y^2 \\ y\left( \dfrac 12 \right) = 2 \end{array}$$
And we also have:
$$\frac{ydy}{1-y^2} =\dfrac {dt}{ 1 -t}$$
$$\frac{dy^2}{y^2-1} =\dfrac {2dt}{ t-1}$$
$$\ln  |{y^2-1}| =2\ln |{ t-1}|+C$$
$$ (y^2-1) =K ( t-1)^2$$
$$ y^2 =1+K ( t-1)^2$$
And $K=12$ from initial condition $(y(1/2) = 2 )$. As @Raffaele commented the only solution is:
$$ y =\sqrt {1+12 ( t-1)^2}$$
Your solution looks good to me. I see no mistakes.

---

$y=\pm 1$ are both solutions of the DE. But they don't satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: In order to get the all solutions I ocould link the proper branch of this solution with $y = \pm 1$ and see all the possibilities, right?

Comment: $y=1$ does not satisfy the initial condition @JoseAf It's only a solution of the differential equation. It's the same  for $y=-1$

Comment: but I could say that a solution would be from  t = - inf to t = 1 equals to your solution and from t = 1 to inf equals to y = 1, right?

Comment: Only $y=\sqrt{12 t^2-24 t+13}$ is the solution, because $y(1/2)=2$. The other root gives $y(1/2)=-2$ and doesn't satisfy the initial condition

Comment: Yes that's true @Raffaele

Comment: @JoseAf nope it's not a solution to the IVP. Note also Raffaele's comment.

Comment: @Aryadeva Thanks a lot  for the answer. Could you see the plot I put in the question, and tell me if it is a solution too just to clarify my doubt ?

Comment: You're welcome @JoseAf